# Told command dpkg cannot be found

Tags: 12.04, wireless, apt, network-manager, dpkg

On issuing the command `sudo dpkg -i (package name)` at `chronos@localhost ~ $`, I get the response `sudo: dpkg: command not found`. Anyone know why?

I'm trying to load version 3 of network-manager and three related files to correct a known problem accessing wifi in 12.04 on some Toshiba computers, so Ubuntu is offline.

I've downloaded the four files, but I'm unclear on where they should be stored in order for `dpkg -i (package name)` to find them. Could I pursue the installation via apt-get if `dpkg` is actually missing? If so, what would be the correct command syntax?

Comment: Is this an actual problem?

Comment: I got brought here by google searching for "dpkg: command not found". Not sure why something so specific doesn't have a question/answer for newbies. It's maddening trying to learn this stuff!

Answer (score 3):

The original poster, Graubart, [was able to solve their own problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452615/told-command-dpkg-cannot-be-found#comment596819_452620). The Ubuntu system was being `chroot`ed into from another, non-Ubuntu system. But the `dpkg` command was accidentally being issued *outside* of the chroot. By chrooting into the filesystem in which Ubuntu was installed, Graubart was able to run `dpkg` with no problems.

> Okay, I discovered why I couldn't find dpkg--it's in chroot, and I was
>   in chronos@localhost. Switched to chroot, and there it was! Typical
>   greenhorn error, I suppose.

– [Graubart](https://askubuntu.com/users/271496/graubart) [Apr 24 '14 at 3:18](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452615/told-command-dpkg-cannot-be-found#comment596819_452620)

Answer (score 0):

`sudo dpkg -i *pkgname*` is used to install deb file. if you have deb files downloaded then run this command. try to search the hardware driver in hardware  manager.

`apt-get install` command search the software manager which is hosted on launchpad, whether this software is available on software channel.

for example:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

if it is available in software channel, it will install without any problem.

first of all please tell do you have the deb files? is yes then try:

```
sudo dpkg -i <filename>
```

else search the driver in hardware manager. And if still you didn't get the driver install, please reply the model name of your system and wifi model build in the system. so that I can tell you how can you install the drivers.

Comment: Okay, I discovered why I couldn't find dpkg--it's in chroot, and I was in chronos@localhost. Switched to chroot, and there it was! Typical greenhorn error, I suppose.

Comment: Finally stumbled onto how to extract the wifi model information.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that dpkg is missing from your system. If such a thing were possible, you couldn't download and install dpkg without dpkg! What is the result of:

```
dpkg --help
```

If it outputs text about how to use the command, then the command is present.

It doesn't matter where you downloaded the deb files as long as you navigate the terminal to that location first. For example, suppose you downloaded the files to your desktop. Then in the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop
```

Now list the contents of the directory:

```
ls
```

Are all the debs shown?

```
network-manager-3.99-00-ubuntu.deb
some_other_file-ubuntu3.deb
etc.deb
```

If so, install them:

```
sudo dpkg -i network*.deb
```

You can use the wildcard * to keep from typing the entire file name. You can also do:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

dpkg will attempt to install all of them at once and notify you if you have any missing dependencies.

Comment: Tried dpkg --help and was again told the command didn't exist.  As noted, I entered the commands from chronos@localhost~$. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command:

```
:~$ locate dpkg
```

which should be found in /usr/bin/ as /usr/bin/dpkg. I only say this because: if the output from running any command tells you the command cannot be found, than you do not have that command installed.

The output of running a dpkg command where the dpkg binary cannot locate
where the .deb archive is would be something like this:

```
dpkg: error processing archive packagenotfound.deb (--install):
cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
packagenotfound.deb
```

so if the output looks similar to what I have posted the dpkg utility is installed and you need to change directories to the directory where the .debs reside and continue as you previously did.

Comment: I have the same problem as OP. When I go to /usr/bin, the dpkg folder is missing. I was going to use dpkg to install a .deb that I found, which was going to install apt. Not sure why both of these are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try `su -l` (enter your root pass), then `cd` to the dir where you deb file resides and then try again `dpkg -i instertyourdebname.deb`.