# apt: relocation error: version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference

Tags: apt, upgrade, glibc

Since trying to upgrade to 16.04 xenial, I'm getting

```
$ apt
apt: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0: 
symbol _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE7compareERKS4_, 
version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

when simply running `apt`. Needless to say this makes it difficult to do anything.

Any hints?

Comment: wow … this makes me really distrust Ubuntu/Canonical’s upgrade process. Every time I have a **working** but stale version, someone in a help forum tells me upgrades will solve all my problems…I don’t know what a "scratch disk" is, and certainly don’t want to have to interrupt work with `GRUB` debugging…

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The culprit are left-overs from the [PPA for Ubuntu Toolchain Uploads (restricted)](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test), specifically

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
```

There are two possibilities of dealing with this:

- You already have `ppa-purge` installed. Then

  ```
  sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
  ```

  fixes the issues.
- Override the libstc++ by downloading [libstdc++6 for Xenial](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libstdc++6) and installing it via `dpkg -i`.

Comment: At least for me, this fails with message identical to the one in the question...

Comment: Should probably be expanded with answers from below, because obviously `ppa-purge` won't work (same python)

Comment: I get: `sudo: ppa-purge: command not found`

Comment: @Garrett `sudo apt install ppa-purge`

Comment: @NicoSchlömer, thanks, but actually, I believe my `apt` was also not working (as per the original post).

Comment: After I cleaned this up it recurred every time I installed another package with apt.  It looks like some maintenance script in the libc-bin package was blindly updating the libstdc++.so.6 link to point to libstdc++.so.6.0.22.  Removing /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22 solved this problem.

Comment: I had to use the second solution, download the libstdc++6 .deb separately with wget or curl and then dpkg -i --auto-deconfigure on the .deb file.

Answer (score 58):

I had the same problem caused by issues from PPA for Ubuntu toolchain. My computer would not boot because of it. Following @w00kie's comment on his answer, I downloaded (from tty terminal) the debian of package `libstdc++6` for `Xenial` at link https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libstdc++6 and installed using `dpkg -i`. The computer works just fine now.

### Steps

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10_amd64.deb

# I also found this helpful
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Can you please put the commands, step by step in your answer? I'm not familiar with this at all and my linux machine is horked...

Comment: @Zachary What is the exact issue you're facing? Are you able to boot?

Comment: Not really. If I let it go the screen flickers for about 15 mins, then I get a tty2 terminal prompt in a very light grey color. I'm unable to use `apt` (or any tool really). I have even tried to download `libstdc++6...deb` from a bootable USB drive, manually place the package, reboot into the broken system and installing the `.deb` using `sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6...deb`, but it doesn't even know what `dpkg` is.

Comment: That is very unlikely. `dpkg` should be present. See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/452615/told-command-dpkg-cannot-be-found

Comment: I appreciate your statistical analysis, but `dpkg` is not present in what is booting. However, `mv` and `cp` where both available, so I moved the things I wanted to keep into a folder visible from the bootable USB media, copied the files to a thumbdrive and flashed the machine to a fresh install of 16.04. All is well.

Comment: Can you please tell how to download it and install using the terminal itself. I am having the same issue of flickering and apt commands. But dpkg is working.

Comment: To install the `.deb` file, run the following command on terminal: `wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/libstdc++6_5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb`. The link is for 64-bit ubuntu. If you have a 32-bit instead, replace `amd64` by `i386` in the link. You can also open the link in the browser, if that is possible.

Comment: To download/install the .deb file, you can do: `wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2_amd64.deb` and then once that downloads, `dpkg -i libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2_amd64.deb` (assumes 64-bit system).   For me, my internet connection wasn't working, so I downloaded it onto a USB drive from a different computer, then had to manually mount the USB drive on my problematic computer (`sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/usb` where `sdc1` was found by watching terminal output right after plugging in USB ) and then run the above `dpkg` command.

Comment: thank you, I had stuck at flash screen after upgrade from 14.04 until I read this post.

Comment: This also solved my problem. My system (Debian laptop) had the drive fail. I was able to ddrescue most of the drive to a new SSD. It would then boot but couldn't start X with a libvirt failure. I tried to reinstall libvirt and got an error similar enough to OP's that i ended up here. Manually installing the .deb for my distro solved the problem (though a couple other programs have had to be reinstalled).

Comment: I had to use `dpkg --force-all -i libstdc+‌​+6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16‌​.04.2_amd64.deb` to get it installed

Comment: I needed `--auto-deconfigure` as an extra argument to `dpkg -i`.

Comment: That file has apparently disappeared...

Comment: I'm running on a armhf arch, and the link provided doesn't have a download for it. Any idea what to do?

Comment: I had to install several more packages to solve this issue, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1437932/1179344

Answer (score 8):

My comp failed to boot correctly because of this error. Apt-get was not working, nor was Gnome. This was immediatelly after an upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04. I solved it in tty by entering

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

At this point `apt-get` started to work again and I was able to fix all isues from there:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -a --configure
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I also had to uninstall Virtualbox (after the update command) and reinstal it later, but I think this was unrelated.

Comment: i tried this but got an import error on package apt_pkg

Comment: Mixone, what was the exact error and on which command exactly?

Comment: sudo apt-get update   the error came from the python backend i guess, the stacktrace was python and it basically said cannot find module apt_pkg

Comment: Same problem for me too, trying to use the `apt-add-repository` command in your answer gives: `ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0: symbol _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE7compareERKS4_, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in the file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference`

Comment: For idiots like me trying to upgrade 2 years after the release and thinking all the bugs are fixed. 
Link in the comment above is broken. Here is the new one. 

`http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10_amd64.deb` (or `i386` or both)

And don't mind dpkg cursing you. Do `--auto--deconfigure` and your `apt-get` will be back on track afterwards despite error messages. And you will be able to finish with proper `-f --install` + `--upgrade` and reboot into a fresh system.

Answer (score 4):

I had been thinking the problem was something unique to me, and was caused by a download error.

This discussion gave me the clue I needed.  Basically, all that was needed was to replace  libstdc++.so.6.0.22  with  libstdc++.so.6.0.21  in  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  of the failing system. (It seems there's an error in the newer version.)

This can be done from a thumb-drive or, as in my case, from a scratch disk.

Full details at:  https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/395832

Thanks to all...

Comment: I used this trick, but did a dual boot on some spare space.  I was able to easily mount the original partition.  It was pretty easy.

Comment: Awesome - these 3 commands worked for me:   cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/  >>>  sudo rm libstdc++.so.6  >>>  sudo ln -s libstdc++.so.6.0.21 libstdc++.so.6

Answer (score 4):

Following the `dpkg -i` approach in the accepted answer, my 14.04->16.04 upgrade required not one but two packages:

```
gcc-5-base_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_i386.deb
libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_i386.deb
```

After this, `apt upgrade` was able to download the remaining packages and complete the installation.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the latest version of the 'conjure-up' snap installed with Snappy on Yakkety, your apt will be broken with a very similar error:

```
apt: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0: symbol _ZN13pkgSourceList16AddVolatileFilesER11CommandLinePSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS8_EE, version APTPKG_5.0 not defined in file libapt-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference
```

due to this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1a677417

Currently the only workaround I know of is the remove the conjure-up snap (or possibly 'snap revert' it to a previous version if you had one installed prior).

Answer (score 1):

The fix that worked for me was to actually add the Ubuntu toolchain ppa back:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Download libstdc++6 for your ubuntu from Ubuntu package manager website.
   ( use `uname -a` to find the h/w and s/w architecture).
2. Run

   ```
   sudo dpkg --install --auto-deconfigure libstdc++6...deb
   ```
3. Reboot. Ubuntu should boot but apt would not install new packages.
4. To fix dependencies and make system up to date, run these commands

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -f
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix it by typing:

sudo apt-get -f install

without specifing any package. It should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a very similar problem with i386 systems.

To solve the problem, I also had to downgrade gcc-5-base from Version `5.4.1-2ubuntu1~12.04` to `5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4`.

To complete the upgrade to a reasonable-seeming system, I also had to use `dpkg --purge on vituoso_nepomuk` and virtualbox to get rid of their configuration files, which were causing trouble (for me, VirtualBox is provided by package virtualbox-5.1, which seems unscathed by the upgrade.)

The key was to get `dpkg --configure dbus` to work.

To enable wget while in a tty-type screen, users may also need to execute `sudo dhclient eth0` to enable a wired ethernet connection.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this problem when upgrading ubuntu distribution on linux
I saw that:

```
# ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6*
libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6cd*
libstdc++.so.6.0.20*
libstdc++.so.6.0.21
libstdc++.so.6cd -> libstdc++.so.6.0.20*
```

libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6cd -> **libstdc++.so.6.0.20**

But there were two files: libstdc++.so.6.0.21 and libstdc++.so.6.0.20

I've changed the symbolic link to point to latest version libstdc++.so.6.0.21

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
rm libstdc++.so.6cd
chmod +x libstdc++.so.6.0.21
ln -s  libstdc++.so.6.0.21 libstdc++.so.6cd
```

Resulting:

```
libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6cd*
libstdc++.so.6.0.20*
libstdc++.so.6.0.21*
libstdc++.so.6cd -> libstdc++.so.6.0.21*
```

and everything came back to normal

Answer (score 0):

After installing `libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12_amd64.deb` as mentioned in the [answer by Sagar Jha](https://askubuntu.com/a/792471/113421) (this newer version is currently relevant) via `dpkg --force-all -i THE_FILENAME.deb`, I had package dependencies broken in a way that `apt-get -f install` was unable to fix. But `apt` itself is now working. So to get my system back to a working state, I had to explicitly install the specific versions of all the broken packages from the toolchain-r ppa, like here:

```
sudo apt install {gcc-5-base,cpp-5,g++-5,gcc-5,libasan2,libgcc-5-dev,libstdc++-5-dev,libmpx0}=5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12
```

This then let `apt` downgrade and finally lead package system to a consistent state.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing you have to do is copying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 from the normal 16.04 ubuntu.
This is the most simplest way.