# Ubuntu not booting properly after upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: apt, upgrade

I upgraded my 14.04 Ubuntu to 16.04 today after I was prompted to on my home screen. It took a while to download and installation. But after installation step it shows that installation has failed and reverting to preview stage.

Then it crashed and I did a forced shutdown using the power button.

After this my laptop is not booting. It gets to the Ubuntu logo screen and thereafter screen becomes black.

On the top it shows

```
recovering journal 1223921 files of 3927642.
```

I tried command line login using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>f2</kbd> and it worked but when I run `apt-get update` command it throws a relocation error that something is missing in `libstdc++.so.6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having just solved (with the help of [this other discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777803/apt-relocation-error-version-glibcxx-3-4-21-not-defined-in-file-libstdc-so-6)) what looks like the same issue, here's what I did from the terminal:

wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1​_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1​_amd64.deb

then reboot and everything should be fine (at least it was for me so fingers crossed).

Comment: It shows unable to resolve host address 'security.Ubuntu.com'