# Ubuntu 16.04 upgrade problems

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

I was using Ubuntu 14:04 LTS until the upgrade option come up on my screen. I delayed the upgrade because I was not so sure about it.
When I decided to click the upgrade button, the problems came out. It took long time to finish but....now the GUI is no longer available. 
When it start the boot process, seams to bet stack and it doesn't go further. When I click Escape, it gives me the command line prompt. 
How to undo the upgrade or even to get the GUI back?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Does `sudo apt-get update` work for you? If it is complaining about a problem with `libstdc++.so.6`, then [installing the right version of the C++ stdlib](https://askubuntu.com/questions/804944/ubuntu-not-booting-properly-after-upgrade-from-14-04-to-16-04) should fix your problem.

Comment: I tried sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade but none of them was helpful.