# Update 14.04 to 16.04 stuck and won't boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, updates

I used to run Ubuntu 14.04 on parallels and everything was fine. When I upgraded to 16.04 it got stuck on

```
/dev/sda1: clean XXXXXX/XXXXXX files, XXXXX/XXXXX blocks
```

and now it won't boot.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to choose upstart or recovery mode in grub to get into terminal and read some logs?

Comment: I have, but I can't even access grub menu :(

Comment: Looks like it's time for a clean install.

Comment: *sigh* is there any way to recover my files from 14.04?

Comment: Can you boot the live USB?

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu in Parallels on a Mac? Can you get to GRUB by holding down either the LEFT SHIFT KEY or ESC during boot? Are you trying to mount any other (NTFS) disk partitions in /etc/fstab?

Comment: Oh, I've tried to access GRUB but I can't get it to work. I've tried holding SHIFT, pushing it repeatedly, and also booting from recovery mode (which apparently I am not able to do on parallels) and I keep getting this screen. By now I'd be happy to just recover my files :(

Comment: I've run into this same issue (upgraded to 16.04 on parallels and now no GUI.) Ubuntu is booting, but X is not. You can use CTRL-ALT-F1 to get to a terminal to login (or you can ssh into the instance if you know the IP.) I don't know Ubuntu well enough though to understand why X isn't starting.

Answer (score 5):

First, your files are intact, and your system is not "stuck." X-Windows is just not starting. As I said in a comment, you could use CTRL-ALT-F1 or SSH to log into the Parallels instance.

You need to update manually the Parallels tool, which fixes the video driver. You can follow the directions in this KB article.  (It's for an older version of Ubuntu and Parallels, but the steps are the same.) http://kb.parallels.com/en/118776

In summary, you attach the "parallels tools linux iso" (it's in the Parallels.app bundle) to the virtual CD-ROM. Start the virtual machine. Use CTRL-ALT-F1 to get to a text terminal, login, mount the virtual cd, and run the install script. Once reboot, X-Windows will start correctly.

Comment: I followed the steps in your link. It worked for me.

Comment: This saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when upgrade from 14.04 but install `libstdc++6` for `Xenial` will resolve it, got it from [apt: relocation error: version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777803/apt-relocation-error-version-glibcxx-3-4-21-not-defined-in-file-libstdc-so-6)