# How to fix apt libstdc++6 relocation error

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

Upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04 broke my GUI, and I cannot run apt because of a problem with `libstdc++` like in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777803/apt-relocation-error-version-glibcxx-3-4-21-not-defined-in-file-libstdc-so-6).

I downloaded a deb package from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libstdc++6) like advised but I cannot install it with dpkg because

```
installing libstdc++6:amd64 would break libboost-date-time1.55.0:amd64, and deconfiguration is not permitted (--auto-deconfigure might help)
```

What should I do? Do I run dpkg with `--auto-deconfigure`?

Comment: Did you turn off all third party repositories before the update?  Those can cause problems like you have.

Comment: You mean PPA's? No I didn't. How do I know which ones are third party?