# apt-get : relocation error

Tags: apt, package-management

when I issue the apt-get command I receive the following error message:

```
apt-get: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0: symbol _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE7compareERKS4_, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

I run Ubuntu 14.04 on a 64 bit machine.

I am aware of a similar question: [apt: relocation error: version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777803/apt-relocation-error-version-glibcxx-3-4-21-not-defined-in-file-libstdc-so-6)

but none of the advice given there works for me. I have tried several variants of apt-get, like apt-get clean , but I always receive the aforementioned error.

I have also tried

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2_amd64.deb
```

but receive the following error message

```
Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (security.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.26|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

How can I fix things?

Comment: 14.04 : You are trying to get a `libstdc++6` for 16.04 ... May be your corrupt `apt-get` also is from an Ubuntu 16.04 package ? ... Definitely not supposed to work.

Comment: Thanks the input, Knud. It's possible that a 16.04 package caused trouble. How do I find out whether this is true and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> It's possible that a 16.04 package caused trouble.  How do I find out
>   whether this is true and how do I fix it?

Check the version for the installed package 'apt' : `dpkg --list apt` ( If you didn't trash 'dpkg' too.)

The 14.04 version must be `1.0.1ubuntu2*` (The 16.04 version is 1.2.15ubuntu0*)

If dpkg works, you can download `apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.17_[arch].deb` ( like apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.17_amd64.deb or apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.17_i386.deb ) http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/apt

And install with `dpkg -i --force ./apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.17*`