# No desktop and internet after a dirty install of 16.04 from 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, networking, system-installation, upgrade

I have a dual boot system and new ubuntu LTS 18.04 is releasing next month so I want to upgrade my system from 14.04 to 18.04. The best way for the up-gradation is first by going to 16.04 and then to 18.04. Today I upgraded my system from 14.04 to 16.04 and everything seems to work fine but in the middle of the installation of update my system completely freezed and I was forced to restart the system.

After the restart when I went to ubuntu it got stuck in the startup itself

[image]

After that I went to `advance option for ubuntu > recovery mode` where I login to my system in terminal using my username and password. Firstly I tried `lsb_releas -a` command and it confirmed that I have ubuntu 16.04

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.x LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I then did an `apt-get update` but it returned a `relocation error` which I solved using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/911647/158636) (had to install both amd6 and i386 files) by downloading the files using the second windows OS. Then I checked my internet connection using `ping -c 1 google.com` which returned `Unknown host error`. Without internet I cant solve or download any files in my ubuntu. If I have a connection to web in this terminal only ubuntu 16.04 I can definitely solve my other problems. Any idea how to solve this?

After this debacle I am withholding my up-gradation to 18.04. I now want to properly install 16.04

P.S. I dont remember what I did but I have seen `Networkmanger is not running` error in my ubuntu 16.04

if it help my `rfkill list all` looks similar to this

```
0: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: dell-wwan: Wireless WAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

3: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

EDIT

Due to some circumstanceses I cant do a fresh install this forced me to correct my upgradation problems. So I was able to gain my desktop back with new 16.04 and internet back by doing these commands

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
#kept all intemediary prompts in default option ie "N"
#After this restart the systemn
```

Then I restarted the system, this brought back my internet connection and in recovery mode terminal did

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade #not working shows error
sudo apt-get install -f #not working shows error
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Restarted it again now it brought back my desktop but when now my `apt-get` is not working (internet is fine).

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 click : Depends: python3-click (= 0.4.21.1ubuntu0.2) but 6.2-2ubuntu1 is installed
 click-apparmor : Depends: python3-apparmor-click (= 0.2ubuntu1) but 0.3.13.1 is installed
 cpp-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9 is installed
 g++-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9 is installed
 gcc-5 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9 is installed
 libasan2 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9 is installed
 libavformat-dev : Depends: libavcodec-dev (= 7:2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 6:9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.2+fdkaac is installed
                   Depends: libavutil-dev (= 7:2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 6:9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.2+fdkaac is installed
                   Depends: libswresample-dev (= 7:2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but it is not installed
 libboost-context-dev : Depends: libboost-context1.54-dev but it is not installable
 libboost-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev but it is not installable
 libboost-serialization-dev : Depends: libboost-serialization1.54-dev but it is not installable
 libgcc-5-dev : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9 is installed
 libmpx0 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9 is installed
 libproxy-tools : Depends: libproxy1 (>= 0.4.7) but it is not installable
 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings : Depends: libproxy1 (= 0.4.11-0ubuntu4) but it is not installable
 libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager : Depends: libproxy1 (= 0.4.11-0ubuntu4) but it is not installable
 libstdc++-5-dev : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9 is installed
                   Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9 is installed
 libswscale-dev : Depends: libavutil-dev (= 7:2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 6:9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.2+fdkaac is installed
 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 : Depends: libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 (= 2.4.11-0ubuntu0.1) but 2.4.10-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is installed
                      Depends: libwebkitgtk-1.0-common (>= 2.4.11) but 2.4.10-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is installed
 python-kivy : Depends: python-gst-1.0 but it is not installed
               Depends: libsdl2-image-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not installed
               Depends: libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not installed
               Depends: libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I again did `sudo dpkg --configure -a` which showed me these errors

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-kivy
 libswscale-dev:amd64
 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:amd64
 libavformat-dev:amd64
 libunity-scopes1.0:amd64
 unity-scope-mediascanner2
 unity-scope-scopes
```

It seems I have non compatable python-kivy so I tried to purge pyton-kivy

```
sudo apt-get purge python-kivy
sudo apt-get remove python-kivy
```

but again it shows `Unmet dependencies` error. My `apt-get` is not working at all cant install or uninstall apps.any idea how to solve this

Comment: There are so many changes between even 16.04 and 18.04 I would do a fresh install, let alone try to upgrade from 14.04 . IMHO it takes longer to debug failed upgrades than a fresh install and I would almost advise you try 18.04 beta on a live iso and install it if it looks good. At this point you do not have much to loose by doing so.

Comment: any idea how to get back my internet back.. any links?

Comment: Identify your wireless card and google search the chip

Answer (score 0):

I successfully upgraded to 16.04 after my botched upgradation. I have solved `unmet dependency` error [by changing the server](https://askubuntu.com/a/140251/158636) to a better one.The other problems I solved by finding solution for every single error. Its better to search those error in the internet and use the recommended solutions. I also manually downloaded package files and installed using `dpkg`. These are the important commands which helped me to solve my problem

```
#(Not in any order)
sudo dpkg --configure -a #this is an important command 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f #this is an important command 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo dpkg -i <package name>

#this last one I used after solving my desktop and internet problems
sudo update-manager -d
```