# Error while upgrading from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade

While upgrading using do-release from ubuntu 14.04 to ubuntu 16.04,I encountered the problems mentioned in [apt: relocation error: version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777803/apt-relocation-error-version-glibcxx-3-4-21-not-defined-in-file-libstdc-so-6/851351) so while doing the methods given in the above question,I am encountering the following problems

```
 dpkg: error processing package libstdc++6:amd64 (--install):
 package libstdc++6:amd64 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9 cannot be configured 
 because libstdc++6:i386 is at a different version (7.2.0- 
 1ubuntu1~14.04)
 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 libstdc++6:amd64
```

Comment: You are trying to replace libstdc++6 with a different architecture, amd64 vs i386.

Comment: But my current architecture is x86_64 ,I don't have any idea how i386 ended up there