# sudo apt-get dist-upgrade giving errors, unable to open Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, glibc

I'm trying to do `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` for upgrades all of the packages on the Linux system (14.04). In the middle, it gave an error and I ran `sudo apt-get install -f`, the PC got rebooted and went into recovery mode.

Tried to open Ubuntu it’s giving like:
[image: Failed to load Kernel modules Image]

Then it’s going to another window for login:
[image: Login Image]

In this, it is showing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but I only use command `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04, why is it showing 16.04? This `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` command is for kernel upgrades all of the packages in Linux system. Why is this happening?

After logged in, it’s giving `apt-get: relocation error`:
[image: apt_get relocation error Image]

Error message after login:

> $ apt apt: relocation error:
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0:  symbol
>   _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE7compareERKS4_,  version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link
>   time referenc

Methods tried to solve the error:

1:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
```

It is giving the response no file or directory like this is not there.

2: Then I tried this way

```
 # ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6*
libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6cd*
libstdc++.so.6.0.20*
libstdc++.so.6.0.21
libstdc++.so.6cd -> libstdc++.so.6.0.20*
```

Which giving response permission denied.

3: For this commands, it’s giving the response command not found.

```
gcc-5-base_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_i386.deb
libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_i386.deb
```

For me no need to update PC to 16.04. I just want to update the kernel modules. How can I solve this apt-get relocation error without loss of data in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Did your system have a GUI originally and do you want to restore it? I think you are running 16.04 now actually, the reason might be a wrong command or wrong contents in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. The upgrade might not be done correctly but since you can log in to the terminal, everything can be fixed using the right commands.

Comment: @Melebius i dont want to install 16.04. I can run commands on terminal . Which commands i need to fiz this issue? What commands i need to follow.

Comment: I am sorry, you seem to have upgraded to 16.04 (at least partially) and there is (almost) [no way back](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version) unless you have a backup. To get rid of the errors, check https://askubuntu.com/questions/777803/apt-relocation-error-version-glibcxx-3-4-21-not-defined-in-file-libstdc-so-6 if it helps. However, you should check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` first, whether it points to `trusty` or `xenial`. If you’re in doubt, add the contents to your question.

Comment: @Melebius The method you suggested i tried that its giving no  file or directory found. Is threre any proper way?

Comment: Please post the exact command you executed, character after character. I haven’t recommended any commands yet. BTW the codes you used in part 1 and 3 of your question are not commands, just file names.

Comment: @Melebius Please check the images and give a solution.

Comment: The images primarily show a potential problem with your sources. @Melebius in the first comment suggested checking your sources (wrong contents in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or in a file in the sources.list.d/ subdirectory) that has caused the dist-upgrade to include xenial sources (thus [part] jump you to xenial/16.04).  If you `grep xenial /etc/apt/sources.list` you should get no output  (inc. the subdir), but I suspect you do have output (or 16.04 sources) which is I believe the cause for issues.