# Black screen after ubuntu 16.04 upgrade on VirtualBox

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, virtualbox

When Ubuntu 14.04(Lubuntu) was working fine, updated latest of 14.04(Not 16.04). Then following error started to appear after login:

```
VBoxClient: VBoxClient (seamless): failed to start. Stage: Setting guest IRQ filter mask Error: VERR_INTERNAL_ERROR
```

[image: Message after lubuntu login]

---

Ignoring the above message went for upgrade to 16.04. After successful upgrade, rebooted. Now I can only see black screen after splash screen. Can anyone help with this?

Just before black screen-

```
Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Additions service.
```

[image: dmesg log during splash screen]

[Full Video](https://youtu.be/-XXV4BKD0vI)

Comment: is it possible to boot to a busybox by holding shift? if so you should attempt uninstalling any virtualbox apt package you find. `sudo apt purge virtualbox-guest-additions -y && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt full-upgrade -y && sudo reboot`

Comment: The command on the shell (recovery mode) is failing with `apt:relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0 ...` [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/HUU5xDR.png)

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure  -a && sudo install -f && sudo dpkg --force-all --remove virtualbox-guest-additions`

Comment: my bad try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92256/discussion-between-nilesh-and-tatsu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run the following to fix your packages and system :

```
sudo apt install -f && sudo apt purge virtualbox-guest-additions -y && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt full-upgrade -y && sudo reboot
```

Comment: apt command was failing due to `apt:relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0` [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/HUU5xDR.png)

This solution worked after resolving libstdc++ problem using https://askubuntu.com/a/792471/895417

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused due to upgrading kernel without uninstalling virtualbox guest additions. The reason for `VERR_INTERNAL_ERROR` may be the same.

Go to Recovery Mode and use root shell to uninstall virtualbox guest additions, fix broken packages and complete upgrade process.

Detailed steps:

1. Hold down left <kbd>Shift</kbd> just after virtual box splash screen. It will take you to grub menu
2. Select the first `Recovery mode` menu
3. Select `Enable networking`. This will automatically mount disk in read/write mode
4. Select `Drop to a root shell` menu
5. Use following commands to finish upgrade, fix broken packages

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10_amd64.deb

sudo apt install -f

sudo apt purge virtualbox-guest-additions -y
#Or you may run /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions~/uninstall.sh and sudo dpkg -purge unity-scope-virtualbox

sudo apt autoremove -y
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt full-upgrade -y
sudo reboot
```

This should solve the problem.

**Remember!** Never upgrade without uninstalling virtualbox guest additions, the culprit.