# apt-get relocation error after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I just upgraded to Ubuntu xenial, 16.04. When I try to do apt-get, I get the error

```
apt-get: relocation error: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0: symbol [long symbol omitted] version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

I tried solutions at [apt: relocation error: version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777803/apt-relocation-error-version-glibcxx-3-4-21-not-defined-in-file-libstdc-so-6):

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10_amd64.deb
```

but the system complains this is going back to an old version of libstdc++6:

```
dkpg: warning: downgrading libstdc++6:i386 from 8.1.0-5ubuntu1!14.04 to 5.4.0-6ubuntu~16.04.10
```

and refuses to continue because `libstdc++6:i386 break libkolabxml1`.

That page also suggests using `ppa-purge` (but it's not installed) and `apt-add-repository` (but `apt` isn't working).

I have also tried installing `aptitude` itself, the xenial version for i386. It complains that it needs `libcwidget3v5` and `libsigc++-2.0-0v5`. But it can't install these because it breaks dependencies if it tries.

When I've run across a mess of dependencies like this before, it turned out I had something at the top level that was of the wrong sort.

What's the fix? I'd imagine if I can get `apt` working, I can get other things repaired. I'd be willing to run the upgrade process again, but `do-release-upgrade` fails because it can't use `apt`.

---

Some further requested detail.

Output of `dpkg --print-architecture`: `i386`

Output of `dpkg --print-foreign-architecture`: [no output]

Output of `ldd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0 | grep local`: [no output]

Output of `ldd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep local`: [no output]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the outputs of `dpkg --print-architecture` and `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`

Comment: Please add output of `ldd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0 | grep local` and `ldd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep local` to the question.

Comment: Output requested, done!

Comment: `pkconf  refresh` and `pkcon  get-updates` also `pkcon repo-list` maybe this way we get an overview.

Comment: Please see `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and see the track of depends `ldd /usr/bin/apt-get`.

Comment: I have given up on this and did a complete reinstall of the operating system. Currently trying to get my old software back on it. Thanks to all.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1437932/1179344

Answer (score 1):

Try forcing the installation of libstdc++6 by using:

```
dpkg -i --force-downgrade --force-depends libstdc++6...
```

If they don't work, you can also try `--force-all`.